# JQuery cross-site request with credentials

Tags: jquery, ajax, cors

As the tittle says, i'm trying to access a cross-site REST service, using JQuery with CORS.
The problem are the credentials. I followed some answers from this site, but it seems my code is not sending any validaton data since it asks for the user and pass opening a window. I'll show some code so you see it:

JQquery:

```
$.ajax({
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {},
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function(e){}
});
```

When the AJAX request is made, as i said, a window appears asking for username and password. This shoud not appear, since the user and pass are in the AJAX request! If i put the user and pass it works, so the validaton works fine on destination server.

Thanks for your time! Sorry about my non-native english writing =D.

Comment: By avoiding comma splices you've surpassed 90% of native English-speaking programmers already. :-) Welcome to SO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use Basic Auth and Jquery and Ajax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax)

Answer (score 1):

For cross-domain requests, setting the **content type** to anything other than `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data`, or `text/plain` will trigger the browser to send a preflight `OPTIONS` request to the server.
Also the `error` handler is **not called** for cross-domain script and cross-domain JSONP requests, so you wont be able to handle it. This is an [Ajax Event](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/).

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for details and another great article on how to make cross-domain requests with CORS [here](http://www.eriwen.com/javascript/how-to-cors/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the content type is set to text/plain. 
I will check about the error handler later =)

Answer (score 0):

There is no username and passwort options, you should put this in the request data, like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        username: 'user',
        password: 'pass'
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: {
          withCredentials: true
    },
    success: function(data) {},
    error: function(e){}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i tried what you say and it still asks for user and pass.

Comment: Than you should explore how the site you connect with expects the login data. Sometimes you need a GET request with pass and user as URL Parameter. Some APIS expect credentials in JSON. It is hard to tell from here how your desired REST Service works. I only pointed out, that passing pass and user as ajax options is wrong.